# How does c# interpret my query?

Tags: c#, linq

Why does:

```
 var allShapes = _context.AttributeValuesLibraries.Where(x => x.AttNameID.Equals(1)).Select(y => y);
```

work, but I get the error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context" when I exclude the Select() like:

```
var allShapes = _context.AttributeValuesLibraries.Where(x => x.AttNameID.Equals(1));
```

Is there another way to write this query so it makes more sense? I just played with the query to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var allShapes = _context.AttributeValuesLibraries.Where(x => x.AttNameID == 1);
```

It really depends on your Linq provider.